# Вывод списка в каждой записи в Detail области

Tags: java, jasperreports

Есть структура:

```
public class ViewingPosition {
    ...
    /**Наименование позиции*/
    private String itemName;

    ...

    /**Список коэффициентов*/
    private List<ViewingCoefficient> coefficients
    ...
}
```

Список `ViewingPosition` задаю как источник данных `JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(список_ViewingPosition);`
и спокойно им пользуюсь в Detail области.
[image: шаблон]
[image: отчет]
Как вывести список `List<ViewingCoefficient> coefficients` в каждой записи detail?

Answer (score 0):

Определите переменную (**Variable**) типа `String`, прикрепите к ней **Expression**, который трансформирует `List<ViewingCoefficient>` в строку. В **band'е Detail** добавьте **Text Filed**, у которого **Expression** эта переменная.